# invalid conversion from 'void* - casting

Tags: c++, casting

I have an issue with a code that compiles without problem under gcc but not with g++. I am moving to g++ since I would like to make use of boost for some multithreading improvement. The errors I get are something like:

```
invalid conversion from 'void* volatile' to 'TrialVect*'
```

the piece of code is:

```
static void funcSize( struct TrialVect *vector ) {
  if ( vector->field ) {
    struct TrialVect *ptr = BO2V (vector->first,vector->second);
   }
}
```

As I googled there is some issue with casting variables, why? suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: implicit conversion from void* to other pointer types is a C thing, which seems to be language these snippets are written in. C++ does not have implicit conversions of that kind. Either do a manual cast, or rewrite your code in proper C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ any pointer can be converted **to** `void*` implicitly, but converting **from** `void*` requires an explicit cast.

Try this:

```
auto ptr = static_cast<TrialVect* volatile>( BO2V (vector->first,vector->second) );
```

`volatile` is an attribute (like `const`) that must be handled separately; either the new pointer must match the old one, or you can change the `const`/`volatile` attributes using a separate `const_cast`. For example,

```
auto ptr = static_cast<TrialVect*>( const_cast<void*>( BO2V(vector->first, vector->second) ) );
```

Whether removing the `volatile` attribute is safe or not depends on the application.

Comment: And the `volatile` in your first snippet should apply to pointer, not `TrialVect` :)

Comment: @LogicStuff I think I might just go back to bed :)

Comment: @Tiutto please try again, I have fixed the snippet.

Comment: `static_cast<TrialVect *>(BO2V (vector->first,vector->second))` should be enough. Even if `BO2V (vector->first,vector->second)` is a macro that expands to a `volatile`-qualified lvalue of type `void*`, after the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion has been applied, you just have a value of type `void*`, no `volatile` anywhere in there. (Or perhaps the error in inside the `BO2V` definition itself, in which case no operation on the result will make a difference. I'm guessing that's not it, but I can't rule it out.)